# Can the term 'loss of service' be used to describe a service offered to an unsatisfactory standard?

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to get a full refund for my services with my Internet Service Provider. My speeds are extremely slower than usual and they have recognised that the problem is their own fault.

I am attempting to receive a full refund or service upgrade from one of their customer service representatives, but they say they can **only give a full refund in the event of a service loss**. They refer to [this page](http://store.virginmedia.com/the-legal-stuff/terms-and-conditions-for-fibre-optic-services/loss-of-credit-guidelines.html) which does state that technically a full refund should be provided for a **loss of service** (depending on the number of days in that month).

Could the word 'loss' therefore also mean an unsatisfactory service being provided, or does it *have* to mean that I have no service?

Thanks!

Comment: standard IANAL warning, but my interpretation would be that "loss of service" = "service is completely unavailable", not "service is available but performs like a slug."  So you're not gonna get a full refund.

Comment: Did you prepay for service? Unless you have a more specific "service level agreement" I think you're on the hook for the full amount.

Comment: It's a contract and paid with Direct Debit. There's probably something more technical in the contract but I don't really fancy trawling through that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires a judgement to be made on the legal usage of a polysemic word.

Comment: The page says "loss due to a fault".  That latter part is pretty important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word **[loss](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loss)** has numerous meanings, among them

> - the disadvantage or deprivation resulting from losing   ⇒ a loss of reputation
> - the person, thing, or amount lost   ⇒ a large loss
> - (plural) military personnel lost by death or capture
> - (sometimes plural) the amount by which the costs of a business transaction or operation exceed its revenue
> - a measure of the power lost in an electrical system expressed as the ratio of or difference between the input power and the output power

In each of these meanings, the loss is not necessarily total. There is a diminution of some, but not all, of the thing being referenced.

In the case of service, a reduced level of functionality to the point that is is not useful or satisfactory may be considered a *loss.* Whether the amount of loss is sufficient to warrant a particular credit is a question of contract, not language.

Comment: It isn't made clear what 'loss' actually means on the site I provided. Glad to know that there are other interpretations of the word that make it so that a loss does not necessarily have to be total, as you said.

Answer (score 2):

To my ear, "loss of service" means that something went faulty with your provider to such a degree that you can't get access to the service anymore.

An unsatisfactory service would be more likely referred to as "poor quality of service" or the like.